# Is it possible for an Angular 2 mat-select to have a different mat-select box width than the mat-select-panel?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, html-select

I am having trouble with the material mat-select initial selection box for the "drop-down" menu's width being the same size as the options in the mat-select-panel.  I previously had a simple jQuery selection box, that had one width for the placeholder and a separate width for the selections/options.  It seemed to do this automagically.  I am now having trouble with Angular 6 material selection to have the different widths.  It took me forever to find out how to change the widths in the first place. I finally changed it by using

Angular HTML:

```
<div id="selectionList">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat select [ngclass]="{'selection-box-width' : true }" placeholder="Select an Option">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let selection of selectionList">
    Your {{selection.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and SCSS of

```
.selection-box-width {
    min-width: 512px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

The selection box (mat-select) always has the same width as the popup higher z-index (mat-select-panel).  Should there be a way to change the widths and have them different?

Answer (score 1):

I step back as to who answered this question.  It was both of you, for me to get a better understanding of the concept.  I found out there was a little bit of CSS I needed though.  My code is as follows:

```
<div id="selectionList">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat select panelClass="panel-selection-width" placeholder="Select an Option">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let selection of selectionList">
        Your {{selection.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and, in the **styles.scss**, a SCSS of:

```
.panel-selection-width {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

the !important is definitely needed, but the **[ngclass]="{'selection-box-width' : true }"** was not needed.  I did need this in the SCSS of the component:

```
#selectionList > .mat-form-field {
    min-width:250px;
}
```

But it works now!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to style both. Styling for the panel needs to be applied via the `panelClass` option. Using `ngClass` will apply style to the select input, but not the panel.

```
<mat-select 
    [ngclass]="{'selection-box-width' : true }" 
    panelClass="selection-panel-width" 
    ...
```

For the panel, you will probably have to use `!important` with the max-width setting and possibly others, and the class need to be a global class, not part of your component.

Comment: Your answer seemed very promising, but it doesn't seem to take the SCSS of my app.component.scss to apply to the mat-select-panel.  I've entered a .selection-panel-width to the app.component,scss, but it doesn;t seem to effect it.  It has an entry in the <div> of 'ng-reflect-ng-class="selection-panel-width"' but the 'max-width' seems to be stuck at '280px' for .mat-select-panel's css.

Comment: Did you define the selection-panel-width class in your global style sheet and use the !important modifier for the max-width setting?

Comment: Your are correct, I put the class definition in the app.component.scss file and not the styles.scss.  I put the .selection-panel-width in the styles.scss, it works.  Thank You!!!